# Jquery Resize Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Why is there such a terrible delay in my code. I want this div to slide in and slide out based on the window dimensions. But every time there is a delay. It's never the same length. Should I be using a timeout function? Or is there something wrong with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><style type="text/css">div {
  background-color: brown;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  left: -120px;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div style="display: block; left: 0px;" id="navg">Chocolate!</div>


<script>var navg = $("#navg");
var wind = $(window);

wind.load(function() {
  if (wind.width() > 900) {
    navg.show();
    navg.animate({
      left: "0px"
      }, 1000);
  } 
});

wind.resize(function() {
  if ((wind.width() < 900) && (navg.is(":visible"))) {
    navg.animate({"left":"-120px"}, 1000, function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  } else if ((wind.width() >= 900) && (navg.is(":hidden"))) {
    navg.show(function() {
      navg.animate({"left":"0px"}, 1000); 
    });
  }
});
</script></body>
```

Here is a link to the code in Liveweave: http://liveweave.com/HWpQUe
Try resizing to get a better idea of what I mean.

Comment: Seems to be working as intended for me. By delay, do you mean the speed of the square is slow? If so, just reduce the number `1000` (three instances of it in your code here) to `200` or `400` and see what works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your post Hamza, but what I mean is that if I resize the window multiple times, it will not trigger the function. Sometimes I will resize the window and have to wait for 30 seconds before the popup occurs.

Comment: Ah, what's happening there is that you have multiple animations running over each other, and possibly stopping each other from ending. You probably want to use http://api.jquery.com/finish/ before starting each animation, to stop any previous animation.

Comment: Hamza, I don't know how to mark your comment as the answer. I'm new and I must not be able to yet, but it definitely solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'll add the comment as an answer... I don't think comments can be upgraded to answers (or I don't know how).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening there is that you have multiple animations running over each other, and stopping each other from ending. You probably want to use api.jquery.com/finish before starting each animation, to stop any previous animation(s).